# Can I transfer a GTA online character from one Xbox live account to another?

Tags: xbox-network, grand-theft-auto-online, rockstar-games-social-club

How can I transfer a GTA online character from one Xbox live account to another? I have been playing on my dads Xbox live for the past year. I have recently gotten my own Xbox live account but I don't want to loose my GTA online character. Is there a way for me to transfer the data?

Comment: @FinnRayment I don't think that's the correct duplicate. The one you linked is about transferring between physical consoles, while this one is to transferring the GTA Online character from one Xbox Live account to another

Comment: @PrivatePansy Oh my god! I totally didn't notice that!